# How to access secure url using webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to access secure url via web client and getting few errors.
Overall purpose is download an image from secure url..

Please note that earlier, I was able to download image from repository with http and now they have enforced (security) https in same url.
We have a console application which runs on periodic basis and pulls image from server and stores locally.

Please advise as what I am doing wrong ? or what is missing ?

Following are the issues I am facing.

1. /// if I use code section 1... I get error saying Parameter is not valid.
2. /// if I use code section 2... File gets saved to local but get a message " File appear to be corrupt or large and not able to open.

Section 1 and 2 are listed below.

```
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {

                webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("id", "pwd");  // if credentials are wrong...still I get the imageByte

                /// section 1 - if I use this code... I get error saying Parameter is not valid.
                // ----------------------------- Start --------------------------------
                imageByte = webClient.DownloadData("https://someurl/source/abcd.jpeg");
                ////Initialize image variable
                Image newImage;
                ////Read image data into a memory stream
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length, true))
                {
                    ms.Write(imageByte, 0, imageByte.Length);

                    //Set image variable value using memory stream.
                    newImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true, false); // Throws error at this line saying that parameter is not valid.
                }
                newImage.Save(@"location\image.jpeg");
                // ----------------------------- End --------------------------------


                /// section 2 - if I use this code... File gets saved to local but get a message " File appear to be corrupt or large and not able to open.
                // ----------------------------- Start --------------------------------
                webClient.DownloadFile("https://someurl/source/abcd.jpeg", @"location\image.jpeg");
                // ----------------------------- End --------------------------------

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both errors say that the data which was downloaded is not a valid JPEG image. Likely it is because some error was returned from the server.

In order to check if server returned an error, you can take a look at what's in HTTP response headers and body.

- For body you can just try to open a file saved in section 2 with a text editor.
- For headers you can check [webClient.ResponseHeaders property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders(v=vs.110).aspx) with debugger or with a simple update to your program.

Example below is taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// Obtain the WebHeaderCollection instance containing the header name/value pair from the response.
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;

Console.WriteLine("\nDisplaying the response headers\n");

// Loop through the ResponseHeaders and display the header name/value pairs.
for (int i=0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)
{       
    Console.WriteLine ("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.Get(i));
}
```

Another ways to see what was actually returned from the server are [Invoke-WebRequest PowerShell cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) or [wget utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (both should support HTTPS and authentication)

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I tried getting the information from response header and didnot see any error as such. I got below response. Pragma = no-cache
Cache-Control = no-cache, no-store
Expires = Thu, 07, 2016 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie = JSESSIONID = "some GUID value"; Path=/abcd/;Secure;HttpOnly
Server = Apache
Content-Type= text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language=en-US
Transfer-Encoding=Chunked
Vary=Accept-Encoding
Date=Fri,12,2016                What I could see is expiry is set to yesterday's date... Could that be an issue ?

Comment: The thing which looks suspicious is Content-Type= text/html - I would expect it to be image/jpeg. Did you try to open the saved file with a text editor (response body should be in UTF-8 text)?

Comment: you are right.. when I open the file in text editor... it worked like charm... and thats the reason i was not able to open the file in any image editor...  so the culprit here is Content-Type =text/html  ... any idea how we can get the type as Image ?

Comment: Well the fact that you were able to open the file with a text editor does not mean anything - you can open virtually any readable file in a text editor. My question was mostly about the content of this file - are there any hints on the actual error in the file? Like "file not found", "server error" or something like that

Comment: No, there are no hints about the error. that file contains the complete HTML of the URL that I had requested.. it contains html, head, script, body,div .... all tags of the page.... so when I hit the secure url into browser... it takes me to a login page which is secure... if I pass my id, pwd.. and click login... I can see the image in that secure system... and the file that I have saved... is the complete html content of the page.

Comment: So does the website just give you (or redirect you to) a login page instead of image? If yes - then you need to do the login procedure first. Login can require something different then just specifying login and password in HTTP request - for example, you may have to do a login HTTP request, submitting some login and password parameters to a different URL, and obtain session ID, and then request the image with this session ID passed as a cookie.

Comment: ok, one more query here is... if its a user ... he/she can login but if request is going through some batch job ? for downloading thousands of image from server... we must have some other mechanism ? which will hit the url, authenticate and download image, save to local.  how we can do via webclient which is part of my console app ? my query might sound basic info.. but any input would be helpful to get image from secure https system

Comment: the url if I am using in webclient to connect.. if I pass in browser... i get a webpage with login window... but if I pass through webclient... I get content type as text/html.

Comment: In order to handle authentication you need to do requests in a way similar to what browser does: do an HTTP request to log in to a web site, obtain session ID, then make another HTTP request to download the image specifying session ID in a way server expects it (cookies?).

Comment: okay, sure, let me check the option... even I am not aware of it.. will google and see the options :) anyways, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're code works fine. 
As Kel suggested most likely the server response header give may give an answer. Are you sure the server is configured to support https?

There is no need to give network credentials. Since HTTPS only is a transport protocol. It secures only the connection.

To do authentication you have to configure the server for example to do BASIC or DIGEST authentication. And if required setup authorization to the requested resource.

One comment on you're code: Don't forget to dispose newImage.